# Replacing/upgrading from R12 to R134 system in 71 C10

Tags: ac, conversion, r12, c10

I am upgrading to R134 in my 71 C10. I have a re manufactured compressor to use R134, I have replaced the POA valve, in the process I have replaced the o rings. Looking at the new POA valve (Old Air) and the old one, I noticed there is no diffuser or metering valve, it is just a hollow empty tube, is this correct or is there something I am missing? I do have a new condenser and filter/dryer from Old Air but I don't find anything that specifies that it as R134 compliant, my call did not get me a specific answer. I have not mounted the compressor yet but will take it to a shop for an overall check and charge for peace of mind. What else can I do to ensure a smooth install and not damage the system for headaches later?
Thanks guys